# bind to remote service(AIDL) form handler class android

Tags: android, android-service, aidl, android-service-binding

I have a remote service which listens for UDP socket. All the UDP send/receives happens via the service. This service starts on boot and last until user uninstalling the service. Multiple apps(client apps) can contact with this service in order to send data via UDP socket.

When message receives to the remote service it broadcast the message. Client apps can catch these broadcasting messages via broadcast receiver. In order to handle the caught messages, client apps have a handler class(plain java class). This handler class needs to bind to the remote service in order to send messages back(to service).

All these communications happens in background(with out interacting with UI)

So how could I bind the handler class with the remote service. Can I use a service connection with plain java class?

Comment: `Handler` has a specific meaning within the Android world. You don't really mean an Android `Handler` here, so maybe you should choose another word instead. It might cause less confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `Service` from a POJO (Plain Old Java Object). You will need access to a `Context` in order for your POJO to call `bindService()`. You can have the client app pass the `Context` as a parameter to the constructor of your POJO, or as a parameter of some other method of your POJO.

Your POJO will need to provide a `ServiceConnection` in the call to `bindService()`. This `ServiceConnection` object will get callbacks when the `Service` is connected and disconnected. Your POJO will need to keep track of whether it has an active connection to the `Service`, so that it can bind to the `Service` when needed.

Be aware that the call to `bindService()` is asynchronous. This means that you will need to wait for the callback `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()` before you can actually call methods on the bound `Service`. The call to `onServiceConnected()` is executed on the main (UI) thread. This may have some implications on the architecture of your application.